# Why isn't the tab-key autocompleting under Xfce4?

Tags: xfce, autocomplete

I have a big problem under Xfce4, namely when I try to start a program using <kbd>alt+F2</kbd>, I'll start typing `xfce4-terminal` and before I finish it, it suggests the end of the sentence--but usually you accept the suggestion by pressing `tab`--here I have to move my hand all the way to the right arrow because tab is just moving the focus from the text area to the other buttons.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: That "big problem" may be solved by (1) always having around a terminal emulator to type various commands in, or (2) hitting enter right after you see the suggestion, or hit <End> to add some options.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky problem is, my friend, when I try to type in `xf` it first complete `xfce4 -` then `ter` and only then I can hit enter. Wouldn't be asking otherwize... alternatively do you know how to alias `ter`to `xfce4-terminal` ?

Comment: Aliases are used in shells, not in desktop environments; in DE's you're supposed to use the mouse to launch the programs... Can't you just start a terminal (via the menus or automatically) at login and do not close it?...

Comment: As with any filename completion, you have to type enough of the command-name or filename to disambiguate it from other matches.  In the case of `xfce4-terminal`, you have to type at least `xfce4-te` if you want to just hit enter to execute it rather than select it from the pop-up menu with a mouse.  Alternatively, have an icon for xfce4-terminal in your panel or on your desktop, or configure your xfce session so that it automatically starts a terminal on login.

Comment: And the autocompletion you expect is a feature of bash when used in a terminal. It may not be available everywhere else. I don't use xfce, but I have `gmrun` set to open with Alt+F2. With that, as soon as I type even `xfc` I get a dropdown of all software starting with those letters. `Tab` allows me to move down the list. I hit `enter` when my choice is highlighted.

Comment: And I know that xfce allows one to set keyboard shortcuts to open applications. So it's not difficult to have Super+T open your favorite terminal, Super+F open Firefox, etc etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alias defined by default for the terminal it's `!` so you just need to press : <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

More broadly you can define your own aliases by going to `xfce-appfinder - Preferences - Actions`

Answer (score 1):

Alt-F2 in xfce4 does not support TAB completion, but it does allow you to hit the up-arrow key to select from the popup-menu via the keyboard.

Try typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> followed by <kbd>xfce</kbd><kbd>Up-Arrow</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish the command-completion, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to Launch the completed command.

On my system, that will run `xfce4-terminal` because it is the bottom-most entry on the popup.  This may be different on your system, just use the up and down arrows to select `xfce4-terminal`.

<kbd>Down-Arrow</kbd> also works, but starts with the selection cursor at the top of the popup menu rather than at the bottom.